# ZSocket.GetOptionString did not work in clrzmq4

Tags: zeromq

*System environment : Windows 7(64bit), VS 2013, Compile in release 64bit*

This is the code:

```
var clients = new ZSocket(ctx, ZSocketType.ROUTER);
clients.GetOptionString(ZSocketOption.TCP_KEEPALIVE));
```

Exception as below:

> ZeroMQ.ZException ""EINVAL(22): Invalid argument""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### `EINVAL ( Error: 22 )` was thrown correctly:

> **`EINVAL`**
>       The requested option *`option_name`* is unknown, or the requested *`option_len`* or **`option_value` is invalid**, or the size of the buffer pointed to by *`option_value`*, as specified by *`option_len`*, is insufficient for storing the option value.

---

### Must fix both of the below listed API non-compliant issues:

1. The ZeroMQ API defines the **`ZMQ_TCP_KEEPALIVE`** socket-configuration option to be of an **`int`** data type, **not** a `string`. Use the appropriate clrzmq4 binding interface function to request an **`int`** typed `option_value` and this first API incompliance will be solved.

> ---
>
> `Option value type           int`
>   `Option value unit           { -1 | 0 | 1 }`
>   `Default value               -1 ( leave to OS default )`
>   `Applicable socket types     all, when using TCP transports.`
>
> ---

2. The ZeroMQ API defines this option to be valid if and only if the socket-instance was equipped with a **`tcp://`** transport-class ( which the `clients` instance, as posted above, was not ). May defer the request to take place after the socket-instance has been instructed to associate a first **`tcp://`** transport-class engine ( be it via a respective use of a `.connect()` or a `.bind()` ).

Comment: Thanks a lot. This problem has been solved with your help. I use 'bool GetOption(ZSocketOption option, out Int32 value)' interface and it works.